# Can't use installed pip package from git

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to install a package from some repo in python.

`pip3 install git+https://path-to-repo.git`

this should have worked fine because when I do `pip3 show package_name` the package is found. However:

```
> python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 13 2020, 10:14:16) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import package_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the installed package?

Comment: 1. You could have multiple Python versions and `pip3` installs packages not for `python3`; check with `pip3 --version`. 2. It could be a problem with the package; we cannot tell without looking at the source code.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

1. Create new conda environment

    `conda create -n new_env`
2. Activate the new environment

    `source activate new_env`
3. Install pip in the new environment

    `conda install pip`
4. Install the package from git

    `pip install git+https://path-to-repo.git`